# How to delete artifacts with classifier from Nexus using REST API?

Tags: rest, maven, nexus, sonatype

I know how to delete a whole GAV using this command :

`curl --request DELETE --user "login:password" http://myNexus/service/local/repositories/myRepository/content/myGroupId/myArtifactId/myVersion`

It works like a charm.

Now I need to just delete an artifact with a classifier, I could not find or read a solution for this.

I wonder if there is a way to delete an artifact with a classifier using the Nexus REST API ?

Comment: I don't have access to a Nexus instance right now, but you can delete only one classifier in the web API which means it is possible. If you have access to log into your Nexus, do it once manually and check the URLs that were requested using your browser's development tools.

Comment: @JeanneBoyarsky, what do you call Web API ? I don't get it.

Comment: @JeanneBoyarsky, what do you call Web API ? I don't get it. Yes I can delete one classifier, I saw this request on logs : http://nexus.nuiton.org/nexus/service/local/repositories/other-releases/content/fr/ird/t3/t3-installer/1.1/t3-installer-1.1-javadoc.jar I could replay this request for another classifier with curl but then only the artifact was deleted and not all others files associateds (*.asc, ...) Any clue about this ?

Comment: This worked perfect for me, I don't have access to the GUI and don't want to rely on an admin.

Comment: The web API is the REST API. It's what you found. If you can't delete what you want in the UI, you aren't going to be able to in CURL.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

To delete an specific artifact, use this command:

```
curl --request DELETE --user "login:password" http://myNexus/service/local/repositories/myRepository/content/myGroupId/myArtifactId/myVersion/myArtifactId-myVersion.jar
```

You need then to ask nexus to rebuild metadata for the gav (otherwise the *.md5 and *.sha1 files will stay on you repository)

```
curl -v --request DELETE  --user "login:password"  --silent http://nexusHost/service/local/metadata/repositories/myRepository/content
```

Comment: For larger repositories, it might be useful to narrow the metadata that is rebuilt by specifying the particular section of the repository in the URL.  For example: `http://nexusHost/service/local/metadata/repositories/myRepository/content/com/myCompany/myProduct/artifactName`.