# Remove artifact from nexus without GUI

Tags: maven, build, repository, nexus, artifact

Is there any way to remove artifact from nexus repository without GUI, or rewrite releases and clean just snapshots?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to delete artifacts with classifier from Nexus using REST API?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34115434/how-to-delete-artifacts-with-classifier-from-nexus-using-rest-api)

Comment: Take a look at the linked question. You can send a HTTP DELETE request to do that.

Answer (score 0):

Sure, you can use the rest API:

http://blog.sonatype.com/2012/07/learning-the-nexus-rest-api-read-the-docs-or-fire-up-a-browser/

I use to build automation as housekeeping, clean, lock and so on with them, if you need help just ask..